# What could cause network latency on a fresh Ubuntu Server 10.10 install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have recently purchased a machine to run an online game server. I put the machine together and have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 10.10. I have noticed that the game server produces a massive amount of lag despite being more than capable of running the server application.

I have been trying to track down the problem all day and now believe it might be something to do with the network connection as when I connect to the server using SSH, on the **local network**, I get a large dollop of lag before the password field appears. Connecting to the old server on the same network displays the prompt instantly.

My hardware is as follows:

```
Core i5 2500 3.3GHz Socket 1155
Asus P8P67 R3 Socket 1155
4GB DDR3 1333MHz
500GB 3.5" SAT-III Hard Drive
```

I use Windows primarily and would ordinarily look for updated drivers if this happened there but I don't really know where to start to solve this problem on Linux.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: There are many potential sources of lag, drivers aren't the most likely culprits. Run `ssh -vvv` and try to figure out which steps are taking abnormally long. Check for messages in the server logs (`/var/logs/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log`). Run `tcpdump -n` as root to see when there's a delay between packets.

Comment: Well the network latency seems to have decided to repair itself for now. I ran `ssh -vvv` and it stopped after: `debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))`

Comment: Stopped, or paused? A small delay at that stage (I think it's at that stage) is expected, because ssh is doing public-key cryptography to generate a session key, and public-key cryptography is slow.

Comment: Sorry paused. Why doesn't this happen on my other (slower) server running the same OS?

Comment: A delay that manifests itself once, then not for a while, then once again, could be due to a cache effect. In particular it could be a slow, but cached, DNS lookup. But it's impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: If I see it again, what information can I give you?

Comment: @Nat: For ssh, primarily where the delay is in `ssh -vvv`. In general, try to get logs or debugging information from both sides. Spy on packets with `tcpdump -n` to see where the delays are. Describe your network topology (any routers involved?). Describe the application: everybody knows ssh, but we have no idea what your game server is doing (for a start, TCP? UDP? Does it have its own protocol, does it make use of other protocols such as DNS at some stages?).

Comment: @Nat I assume that you've checked for actual network issues? such as bad cables/ports... Just because it's on the same LAN doesn't mean there isn't the potential for an actual network problem.

Comment: Hi xeno, yes I checked the cables and even swapped them around. It seems it's likely a DNS issue as when I connect using `<name>` it causes the lag but connecting using the fully qualified domain doesn't lag. I have a loopback set up on my router and my hosts file had some odd entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the times, a annoying small delay when initiating a connection, is due to reverse dns not working. Check your server's primary/secondary dns entries in its `/etc/resolv.conf` and whether they work as expected. As @Shawn J, Goff suggested you can test or work around this by manually entering the ip -> hostname entries of your boxes to their `/etc/hosts` files.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then check the network settings, it is possible to have the wrong gateway or the wrong netmask configured and still be able to use the internet, but not with optimal functionality.

Next step is to check the arp table with `arp -n` (for maybe duplicate entries). Check `arping -I ethX ip.add.re.ss`. If you have duplicated an ip of a machine that is mostly idle, then it is possible to have long delays when connecting and rare disconnects when connected.

Have `sudo tcpdump -ni ethX` running on a terminal during all the testings and watch for dns traffic, icmp messages or arp packets.

Last (and least probable), cabling or nic problems. Look for Link Up/Downs on `dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log`. Create some traffic and watch for retransmits in tcpdump's output or if error counters are increasing in `ifconfig ethX` output.

Comment: It was the DNS lookup, as suspected. In my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I had to change: `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` to `hosts: files dns`.

Comment: I had the same problem, and Nat's solution worked for me. However, now I am at least curious about the reason for this change.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by sshd doing DNS lookups, especially when using SSH keys. You can mediate this by putting entries for your server system's name and your client system's name in `/etc/hosts`.

See http://psomas.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/sshd-reverse-dns-lookup/ for a little more depth.