# LAN network blocks or stops working when downloading "large" files from Internet, what could do that? (I see STP messages in tcpdump output)

Tags: networking, ethernet

This mainly happens when I upgrade my Jetson AGX boxes. I want to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and after a few downloads, the network stops working. It will eventually restart, after the download failed. It can take a minute.

When that happens, the entire network is down for that period of time. All the computers function as normal otherwise (continue to play video, can continue to compile, etc.)

On an idea from @Gilles who posted a comment on [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10476/what-could-cause-network-latency-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-server-10-10-install), I ran tcpdump to see what is happening. The problem happened whenever the network received an STP message on the network.

```
09:00:26.118679 IP _gateway.42102 > panelve.ssh: Flags [.], ack 37541, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 3025122625 ecr 604916587], length 0
09:00:26.118726 IP _gateway.42102 > panelve.ssh: Flags [.], ack 40093, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 3025122625 ecr 604916587], length 0
09:00:26.124774 IP panelve.ssh > _gateway.42102: Flags [P.], seq 40093:40241, ack 512, win 1446, options [nop,nop,TS val 604916589 ecr 3025122625], length 148
09:00:26.166140 IP _gateway.42102 > panelve.ssh: Flags [.], ack 40241, win 1944, options [nop,nop,TS val 3025122673 ecr 604916589], length 0
09:00:27.738519 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [Topology change], bridge-id 8000.a4:b2:39:95:9c:47.800c, length 35
09:00:29.738117 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [Topology change], bridge-id 8000.a4:b2:39:95:9c:47.800c, length 35
09:00:30.193762 IP 192.168.1.2.39763 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 146
```

As we can see, the TCP packets flow as expected until 09:00:26.166140. Then there is a pause and we get an STP 802.1d event. In this specific case, it is too long and ends up failing. Right now, on that network, I see many STP events, every few seconds. There was an outage at that office and all the computers went down. I tried to restart the network switch, but it continues to generate the STP messages.

What else can be done to fix this issue? Is that a hardware problem or would I need to try to reset the switch again? Would I need to turn off everything with a clean shutdown then restart everything? I've never seen such an error before so I'm not too sure what the solution to this one could be...

P.S. note that the network functions just fine as long as I don't try to download *large* files (i.e. tenth of Mb). So I know that the firewall and connections are all still there as expected. Beside, it worked just fine (and fast) before the outage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't really have a good answer for why the `STP` message was generated, but I found the culprit: I had a full managed Cisco switch and **it** was the one generating those messages on the entire network. Once I replaced that switch with a non-managed switch, everything started working properly and really fast as expected.

There may be a way to setup the switch so as to avoid these messages, if you know of such, I'd be glad to listen, although I probably won't take the time to test. But it could be useful for someone else who runs in the same issue. Note that I tested with two such switches so I'm pretty sure that the `STP` messages are part of the scheme of these switches. It probably requires each system to *properly answer* to show queries or something of the sort to properly consolidate the network.

So if you see these messages, you may want to replace your switch with a simpler one.

To see whether the problem was fixed, I used the following command:

```
sudo tcpdump -n | grep ' STP '
```

While I had the Cisco switch, that would happen at least once every other second. Without the Cisco switch, it never happens.